# Rails getting error when using REST to input data

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following code in task.rb:

```
  before_update :update_inspector

  protected
  def update_inspector
    self.inspector_id = User.current.employee.id
  end
```

It works fine.

But, I want to be able to update a task using REST.  So, when using REST there won't be a current user.

So, I tried this:

```
  before_update :update_inspector, :unless => User.current.employee.id.empty

  protected
  def update_inspector
    self.inspector_id = User.current.employee.id
  end
```

But, it doesn't work.

I aslo tried:

```
:unless => User.current.employee.id = nil
```

Thanks for the help !!!

UPDATE1

I also tried this:

```
before_update :update_inspector

protected
def update_inspector
  self.inspector_id = User.current.employee.id unless User.current.employee.id.nil?

end
```

UPDATE2

I'm able to access User.current.employee.id, because this is in my user.rb:

```
 def self.current
   Thread.current[:user]
 end
 def self.current=(user)
   Thread.current[:user] = user
 end
```

UPDATE3

My last try gave me this:

````
  > undefined method `employee' for nil:NilClass

app/models/task.rb, line 30
---------------------------

``` ruby
 25   
 26     before_update :update_inspector
 27   
 28     protected
 29     def update_inspector
>  30       self.inspector_id = User.current.employee.id unless User.current.employee.id.nil?
 31   
 32     end
 33   
 34   end
````

Comment: In the scenarios that don't work I'm assuming that you're update_inspector method is still getting called. Can you log what the `User.current.employee` value actually is. Since this looks to be a class method, is it hanging over from a previous request?

Comment: Define "didn't work." What's `User.current`? Is it set when there's no current user? E.g., is your condition throwing an error before it gets to `employee` (or `employee.id`)? We can't see your code.

Comment: try: `empty?` or `==` instead of `empty` or `=`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're expecting there to *not* to be a current user in some cases, you can't call `User.current.employee` at all, since `User.current` will be `nil`, leading to this error:

> undefined method `employee' for nil:NilClass

How about this:

```
before_update :update_inspector

protected
def update_inspector
  self.inspector_id = User.current.employee.id unless User.current.nil?
end
```

That way, you never even attempt to call the `.employee` method if `User.current` is `nil`. You could further optimize that to avoid the DB lookup of the `Employee` record by using `employee_id` instead of `employee.id`:

```
self.inspector_id = User.current.employee_id unless User.current.nil?
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `User.current` is `nil`. Trying to access any methods beyond that point will result in errors because `employee` is not a method defined on `NilClass`. You should change your condition to:

```
before_update :update_inspector, :if => lambda { User.current }
```

Comment: I don't think that will work since the value of `:if` needs to be either a Symbol, String, or Proc, so it can be evaluated more than once. See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#conditional-callbacks